# Calculus Derivatives - Finding a function, given tangent and x intercepts

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am having trouble solving this problem:

> Find numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ so that the graph of $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ has
>   $x$-intercepts at $(0,0)$ and $(8,0)$ and a tangent with slope $16$ where $x = 2$.

I've tried to find the values by using elimination, finding equations using the $x$ intercepts, but I do not know which direction to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, finding the slope is easy. The derivative of the function at a point $x$ gives the slope at that point. The derivative of the function is $$f'(x)=2ax+b.$$

When $x=2$ the slope is $16$, therefore $2a(2)+b=16$, or $4a+b=16.$ We also know that there is an intercept at $(0,0)$, therefore $$0=a(0)^2+b(0)+c,$$ thus $c=0$. Another point is, $$0=a(8)^2+b(8)+c$$ $$\therefore 64a+8b=0.$$ Solving the two equations $$4a+b=16$$ $$64a+8b=0.$$

We have $a=-4$ and $b=32$, thus $$f(x)=-4x^2+32x.$$

Answer (score 1):

1. $f(0) = a(0)^2 + b(0) + c = 0$
2. $f(8) = a(8)^2 + 8b + c = 0$
3. $f'(x) = 2ax + bx \implies \mathrm{slope \, at \, x=2}: f'(2) = 2a(2) + b(2) = 16$

You should be able to solve it pretty easily if you know how to solve a system of equations with 2 unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach: we know that $f(x)=cx(x-8)$.  Since for any quadratic parabola
$$f'(x)=\frac{f(x+a)-f(x-a)}{2a},$$
we achieve with $x=a=2$ the equation $\frac{f(4)-f(0)}{4}=16$, hence $f(4)=64$, thus $c=-4$.